# Is there a way to query a table referencing the result column for prior periods?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c

#### The Problem

I want to perform a query using the aggregate results of all time periods prior in the current time period calculations, for each ID.

The solution I have come up with would be to do each time period separately, but this is problematic as the the number of time periods change.

Is there a way to query this using a general approach that does not require hardcoding the result set for each time period?

#### The Math

For each ID in the data the calculations would be as follows

In time period 0 the aggregate should be zero and the equation would be:

[image]

For time period 1 it should be:

[image]

And to show the goal, I'll jump to time period 3:

[image]

For ID1 and time period 3 the result would be:

[image]

As seen in the WANT column in the data below

#### The Data

The data I have is ID, T, B, P and A. WANT is the expected result, and should match R in the equations

| ID | T | B | P | A | WANT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 0 | 25 | 0 | 75 | 0,0000 |
| ID1 | 1 | 25 | 5 | 70 | 1,7857 |
| ID1 | 2 | 20 | 8 | 67 | 2,6013 |
| ID1 | 3 | 15 | 32 | 43 | 14,4275 |
| ID2 | 0 | 25 | 0 | 75 | 0,0000 |
| ID2 | 1 | 20 | 5 | 70 | 1,4286 |
| ID2 | 2 | 17 | 8 | 67 | 2,2004 |
| ID2 | 3 | 10 | 32 | 43 | 10,1425 |
| ID3 | 0 | 25 | 0 | 75 | 0,0000 |
| ID3 | 1 | 25 | 5 | 70 | 1,7857 |
| ID3 | 2 | 25 | 8 | 67 | 3,1983 |
| ID3 | 3 | 5 | 32 | 43 | 7,4300 |

#### Example data

Now with solution provided by gsalem:
[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c6e77/1)

Comment: Looks like a case for  a recursion. Oracle has both old style CONNECT BY and recursive CTE since 11g. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in you dbfiddle:

```
with get_rates (id, t, b, p, a, prt, w) as 
(select id, t, b, p,a, 0 prt, (0+b)*p/A w
 from data
 where T=0
 union all
 select a.id, a.t, b.b,b.p, b.a, b.prt+w,(b.prt+b.w+a.b)*a.p/a.a
 from data a join get_rates b on (a.id=b.id and a.t=b.t+1))
 select  id,t,b,p,a,w
 from get_rates
 order by id,t
```

Comment: This is beautiful! I was working on a similar solution, as Serg suggested recursive with. But I was struggling with parts of the query.